# How can I get mod_xsendfile to guess the MIME type of the file to serve?

Tags: apache2, mime-types, content-type, x-sendfile

I am using [`mod_xsendfile`](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/) to serve static files using Apache. However, I cannot find a way to get Apache to set a `Content-type` header based on the extension of the file it serves using xsendfile. This seems a little odd, since Apache is able to do this when serving static files normally. Is there a way to get Apache to do the same thing when serving files using `mod_xsendfile`?

Comment: @Adrian Nope! Gave up and did it myself, IIRC.

Comment: Thanks. Same thing here. Works, but i'm curious what's wrong...